# Trigger has 100% coverage without a test class

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, code-coverage

I have a custom trigger written on a managed package object. When I run All tests, the trigger shows 100% coverage in SB. However, I am not able to find the class that covers it. I downloaded all the classes in my IDE and searched for the object API name. However, it does not pull up anything.

Also, while deploying to production, it fails.

Can a managed package test class cover a non-managed package trigger? And could it have failed in Production because we ran Default tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, most, if not all, managed packages end up using their custom objects in test classes, so their tests would count towards your coverage. Obviously, as a best practice, you should write your own tests for the object.